# Using `++` in pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, parse-error

Typing the following into a GHC interpreter

```
let describe' all@([x] ++ [y]) = "The first letter of " ++ all ++ " is " ++ [x]
```

yields

> Parser error in pattern: [x] ++ [y]

Why is Haskell unable to match the pattern `all@([x] ++ [y])` against expressions like `"HI"` or `[1,2]`?

Comment: Basically he cant know what is the length of the list and `++` is actually a function so you cant pattern match against it, Haskell pattermatch constructors for example.

Comment: maybe because it's ambiguously?

Comment: So haskell doesn't see `[x] + [y]`, it sees the return value of `++` which in this case is a list of ambiguous size?

Comment: no it just sees the function (`(++)`) and will stop right there with an syntax-error - just as in your other question

Answer (score 9):

let's assume you could pattern-match on `++` - now think about how you could match this:

```
a ++ b = [1,2]
```

you could have:

- `a = [1,2]`, `b = []`
- `a = [1]`, `b = [2]`
- `a = []`, `b = [1,2]`

now what is the right one?

---

the technical reason is that `++` is not data-constructor ;)

---

in your specific situation you could use

```
let describe' all@[x,y] = "The first letter of " ++ all ++ " is " ++ [x]
```

(which will only match strings with length *exactly* 2)

or better

```
let describe' all@(x:_) = "The first letter of " ++ all ++ " is " ++ [x]
```

(which will match all strings of length at least 1)

a safe version would be this

```
describe' :: String -> String
describe' ""        = "your input was empty"
describe' all@(x:_) = "The first letter of " ++ all ++ " is " ++ [x]
```

Comment: Indeed! If pattern matching were that magic, I would try something like `let foo (isProofOfPneqNP s) = "Eureka! " ++ s in foo True` ;-))

Comment: I think this is what the mice build earth for ;)

Comment: ... or [Curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry_%28programming_language%29) (only to say that such constructs are possible in principle).

Answer (score 6):

You may only use constructors in pattern matches. The pattern `[x]` desugars to the pattern `x:[]`, where `:` and `[]` are both constructors. `++`, however, is a function. This is a small flaw of the Haskell language design in that we are unable to quickly distinguish between what symbols we have defined as functions and what symbols come to us from their datatype declarations. For a full treatment, see [section 3 of the Haskell 2010 Language Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17).

Comment: Although, an infix constructor must *start* with `:`, so you can at least identify which functions are *not* constructors. So `++` is definitely not a constructor, while something like `:+` *might* be a constructor.